# How I can inject appsettings and dbcontext to a controller?

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I need to access appsettings and dbcontext on my webapi controller, I read that you can inject them on the controller constructor one or another but not both, there is a way to inject both in the controller?

I already inject appsettings in the controller on the constructor, but I don't know how also inject the dbcontext set in this line of program.cs:

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DBAuthAPI>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AuthAPI"))
);
```

Thank you in advace!!!

Answer (score 1):

I tested with my codes with .net 6 which  inject appsettings and dbcontext to a controller,and it worked well:

First,I checked my appsettings:

```
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SomeDbContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=SomeDbContext-945b4cde-291a-427f-a8c0-4da5ada55b14;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

Then i created  class:

```
public class AppSettingOptions
    {
        public DefaultConnec ConnectionStrings { get; set; }
        public string AllowedHosts { get; set; }
    }
    public class DefaultConnec
    {
        public string SomeDbContext { get; set; }
    }
```

modified  my program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<SomeDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SomeDbContext")));
builder.Services.AddOptions();
builder.Services.Configure<AppSettingOptions>(builder.Configuration)
            .AddSingleton(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AppSettingOptions>>().Value);
```

inject dbcontext and appsettings in controller:

```
private readonly IOptions<AppSettingOptions> _options;
 private readonly SomeDbContext _context;
 
public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, IOptions<AppSettingOptions> options, SomeDbContext someDbContext)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _options = options;
            _context = someDbContext;
        }
```

The result:
[image: Result]